# Problem in installation of PrimeOS

Tags: installation, bash, prime-os

When I want to install PrimeOS, I see a black page with a bash like command line instead of choices for choosing. Is it normal? If it is normal, what should I do and type in the page? In all PrimeOS install guides, there is choice for choosing not a place for typing.

I make USB bootable with ventoy. My OS is LinuxMint.

> Excuse me for my poor english

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the PrimeOS FAQ thread at XDA? https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-beta-primeos-android-for-laptops-pcs-v0-4-5.3858992/page-120#post-78858613

Comment: My problem is not same the link

Comment: Does your system meet the described criteria on described in that forum entry to run PrimeOS (SSE4.2, AMD/Intel graphics, ..)?

Comment: @Robert I think YES: Intel i5-4300U (4) @ 2.900GHz  - Intel Haswell-ULT